# How can I test in bash if the cursor is currently in a text field? (like a text-box in firefox or similar)

Tags: bash, password-store

I'm writing a script for retrieving passwords from [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/). I want it be as efficient to use as possible. I've seen [passmenu](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/dmenu/passmenu) and want something almost the same.

I want to select a password from dmenu, then *if* my cursor is currently in a textbox (say, in firefox), type the password with xdotool, *otherwise* copy it to the clipboard. This way I can use the same script with the same keybindings for everything, without needing a `--type` and non-`--type` version.

(How) can I write the test for whether I'm in a textbox or not?

If I can't, what might be good way to achieve something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: What if your cursor is on a text document open in an editor? Or on a terminal? What if it is on the address bar of a browser? I can't imagine you would ever find a way to make this safe and avoid having `xdotool` type your password in a place where it will be readable. Even if you _are_ on a textbox and in a browser, how would you know if this is a password field? Why don't you just always copy it to the clipboard instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to query with Xdotool the state of the cursor in every application, for as far [as I checked](https://www.mankier.com/1/xdotool).

If your usecase is only Firefox' text boxes, I'd recommend using [native-messaging-hosts script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging). Or even better suited for [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/)words, I'd recommend switching to [gopass](https://github.com/gopasspw/gopass) which is a [Go](https://golang.org/) based implementation of shell based `pass` with additional features and most importantly a [companion Firefox addon](https://github.com/gopasspw/gopassbridge).

The addon is [available in Firefox addons store](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/gopass-bridge/). Note it uses native-messaging to interact with `gopass` on your computer and hence it needs to be setup with:

```
gopass jsonapi configure
```

As explained [here](https://github.com/gopasspw/gopass/blob/master/docs/setup.md#filling-in-passwords-from-browser).